# Tor Server Update

Tags: server, updates, tor

I want to update my Tor server, so I did it like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade tor
```

Output:

```
tor is already the newest version (0.2.9.14-1ubuntu1~16.04.3).
```

Now when I go to the Tor metrics details page, I get an input anyway:

> This relay is running a version of Tor that is too old and may be missing important security fixes. If this is your relay, you should update it as soon as possible.

How can I update my tor server?

Comment: You are running a four-year-old version to Tor on a four-year old OS. Newer versions of Ubuntu have newer versions of Tor. See [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: You didn't give your release details, but the `tor` mentioned appears to be correct for 16.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=tor) so you're using 2016-April software with security patches only backported to them.  If you need a later version, you could upgrade to something more modern, or look for other sources (PPA etc)